# Laravel Testing/phpunit, Too few arguments passed when using dependency injection

Tags: laravel, testing, dependency-injection, phpunit

I'm trying to create a simple test with Laravel. My test code is as below;

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use App\Http\Controllers\Abc\AbcController;

class AbcTest extends TestCase
{

 /**
 * A basic test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */

private $abcController;

public function __construct (AbcController $abcController) {
    $this->abcController = $abcController;
}

public function testExample()
{
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```

However, when i run the test, i'm hitting this error,

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Tests\Feature\abc::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/nex/backend/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php on line 151 and exactly 1 expected in /var/www/nex/backend/tests/Feature/abc.php:28

I've been using this method of performing dependency injections for the rest of my project. I'm not sure why its not working on this particular code.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/testing you should not use Dependency Injection on controller. Instead you should call the endpoint.

Example

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use App\Http\Controllers\Abc\AbcController;

class AbcTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testExample()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/url');

        $response->assertOk();
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to test a certain portion of my code, i.e. a particular API that is sitting in a controller. I will need to call the API. Can you please give me some recommendations on how to call the API with Laravel Test?

Comment: @Ken Not if you are doing unit testing. I think you should call the end point if you're doing feature testing.